# USB Bluetooth dongle stop working

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth, usb, driver, hardware

Windows 7 32bit, Dell laptop. 
I find my **USB Bluetooth dongle** stop working, I used it very rare. When I connected USB dongle, it show 'Unknown device' message, and driver not installed. In taskbar show notifications 'USB device not recognized'.

[image: USB device not recognized]

In `Device Manager` this USB Bluetooth dongle shown as "Unknown device". I tried right click on icon, 'Uninstall Driver Software', then Action > "Scan for hardware changes", it refreshes and show message **driver installed successfully** in windows taskbar. But, in Device Manager, this USB dongle still yellow "Unknown Device". When right click in icon, device status is `"Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43)'` I tried to ininstall every item under "Universal Serial Bus controllers" menu in Device Manager, then rebooted PC, but this not help. I uninstalled all Bluetooth devices from Device Manager, include Bluetooth Radios and Network adapters:

[image: http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf-JAVA/Doc/images/198/c04484518.jpg]

But this not help, too. From [MSDN Bluetooth FAQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn133849%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) I read that Windows 7 include in-box support for Bluetooth. 
How to install built-in the system Bluetooth drivers in Windows 7 and enable Bluetooth? (I need only transfer files, not audio capabilities).

Comment: Not programming related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the problem: USB Bluetooth Adapter dongle is faulty. So this is hardware issue.